# Inherit code file in custom application page within module

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, assembly-references

My application page code

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CustomerCard.aspx.cs" Inherits="HnGTest.Pages.Pages.CustomerCard, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" MasterPageFile ="~masterurl/default.master" %>
```

while my code file structure

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using HnGTest.DataEntities;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace HnGTest.Pages.Pages
{
    public partial class CustomerCard : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage 
    {}
```

element.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Pages" Url="SitePages">
    <File Path="Pages\CustomerCard.aspx" Url="CustomerCard.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Aspx and cs file within module that solution architexture structure like

[image]

but while I deploy I get an error:

> **"An unexpected error has occurred.  "**

Update : public partial class CustomerCard :

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with more details? Does the error occur when you deploy the WSP, or when you activate the feature? Do you have a message in the logs? An excerpt of the elements.xml file? Is the DLL correctly deployed to the GAC?

Comment: Feature activated successfully, but while open page from page library error throw  and dll file is availabale in GAC folder @Evariste

Comment: Thanks for these info. There must be a more detailed message: you can get it either from the ULS logs, or directly in the browser if you edit the web.config so it is displayed automatically (see for instance http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/73798/35604)

Comment: In ULS log error  "UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized." and all that web.config setting done as said @Evariste

Comment: And no more explicit error in the browser? In the ULS logs you should also have Something more explicit... "UserAgent not available" is a generic error not directly related to your problem :(

Comment: Not any specific error in log.@Evariste

Answer (score 1):

After looking more carrefully at the code-behind, I noticed you inherit from `LayoutsPageBase`. However, your page is not an application page (inside _layouts), but a module (a file provisionned in a library).
I've never seen a module .aspx page inheriting from it, but always from `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage`. That may be the problem.

Comment: I tried but not worked in my situation @Evariste

Comment: I update code to class inherit from "Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage" but this try also failed :(..@Evariste

Comment: We definitely need a more detailed error message, either by modifying the web.config or from the ULS logs...