# ItemUpdating event receiver method yielding COMException in MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, document-library, event-receivers, exception, item-updating

I implemented an event receiver and attached it to a MOSS 2007 document library. I overrode the synchronous `itemUpdating` method and perform some validation before letting the update operation proceed. In case validation fails, I use the following code to cancel the update and indicate an error to the user:

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdating(properties);
    // Perform some validation...
    if (/*validation fails*/)
    {
        properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError; // line 1
        properties.Cancel = true;                                  // line 2
        properties.ErrorMessage = "Validation error";              // line 3
    }
}
```

I expected to see the SharePoint error page with a display of the error message. Instead, I see the rather unamiable IIS server error page with the full stack trace.

I switched around lines 2 and 3, and I even replaced `SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError` with `SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelNoError`, to no avail. Any ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "yellow" ASP.NET error page is probably due your "dev" web.config configuration that shows up raw errors (see [How to set customErrors attribute in sharepoint 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73788/how-to-set-customerrors-attribute-in-sharepoint-2013)).

However, `ErrorMessage` will always end-up with an error message to the end-user, just less ugly than the yellow one. No way to display a nice warning box :(

Comment: Thanks... it was my dev environment web.config. I followed that article and updated the settings to not display custom/full errors.